# correct approach for 2 threads alternatively printing numbers

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a program which creates a 2 new thread and shares a common lock object to print numbers alternatively.
Wanted to know if the approach for using wait() and notify() is correct?

Main Class

```
public class MyMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
MyThread1 obj = new MyThread1();

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(obj);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(obj);

    thread1.setName("t1");
    thread2.setName("t2");

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
}
}
```

Thread Class

```
public class MyThread1 implements Runnable{
    int i = 0;
    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        while(i<10)
        {
            if(i%2==0)
            {   
                try{
                    notify();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" prints "+i);
                    i++;
                    wait();

                 }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
            }else
            {
                try{
                    notify();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" prints "+i);
                    i++;
                    wait();
                }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can there be a better usage of wait() and notify() instead of using it in both the if conditions?

Comment: I think it would be more appropriate at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Cheers.

Comment: You should tell your instructor that there is no _correct_ approach because making two threads take turns like that is a completely wrong thing to do.  The exercise will teach you something about _how_ to make threads communicate with each other, but it is a perfectly awful example of _when_ to make them communicate.  Of course, threads ultimately must communicate with one another, but the less often they do it, the more benefit you will get from using threads.  In real software, most of the time, your threads should each be off doing their own independent thing.

Comment: P.S., I would not use `wait()` and `notify()` unless the instructor specifically told me to use them.  `wait()` and `notify()` are the absolutely most primitive means available to you for communicating between Java threads.  They should be used to implement higher-level "synchronization objects" such as blocking queues and semaphores (many of which are already provided for you in the `java.util.concurrent` package). Your programs will be easier to read if you write them using the higher-level abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

Since there you have some code repetition I'd just go with something like:

```
while(true) {
    //If it's not my turn I'll wait.
    if(i%2==0) wait();

    // If I've reached this point is because: 
    // 1 it was my turn OR 2 someone waked me up (because it's my turn)
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()": "+i);
    i++; // Now is the other thread's turn
    // So we wake him up
    notify();
}
```

Also, be very careful with monitor's behaviour. (Thread waiting/notifying queues).

Comment: You should replace `if(i%2==0)` with `while(i%2!=0)`.  It's good practice to always loop when awaiting a condition. The reason is, if your code gets re-used in a multi-consumer app, then it can not be assured that the condition will still be true after the `wait()` returns:  Another consumer may have already dealt with it.

Comment: I am aware of that, and also of the spurious wake-ups but since he used an "if" statement I wanted to do the same thing.

Comment: [too long to add in an edit]
There's another whole discussion whether you should or you should not put a while instead of an if statement. It also depends of the implementation of the monitor that you're using; that is exactly why I pointed out to be very careful with monitor's behaviour since java monitor implementation or reentrant locks (java library) or python monitors (for instance) do not behave the same way.

Using "pure" monitors; Hoare's 1973 specification, with an if statement is enough. But I'm all with you that in this case it is better to use a while since this is java.